# if statement with build errors

Tags: c#

What is wrong with my if statement?  I am trying to get a button to only log in when the username is "username" and the password is "password".

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if UserNameTextbox.Text = "UserName" 
                && PasswordTextbox.Text = "password" 
            {
            GameSelect gs = new GameSelect();
            gs.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does `Syntax error, '(' expected` not give you any clues?

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues, first you need brackets around your conditions. Second your equals should be double equals to act as a compare (not an assign). In fact I'd actually recommend .Equals() as you can explicitly define case sensitivity.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (UserNameTextbox.Text == "UserName"  && PasswordTextbox.Text == "password")
  {
    GameSelect gs = new GameSelect();
    gs.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning values to textboxes instead of checking their values.
Use == instead of =:

```
if (UserNameTextbox.Text == "UserName" && PasswordTextbox.Text == "password"){

}
```

Also you do need to put () around your if clause.

Answer (score 2):

With `=` you assign a value to a variable. With `==` you check for equality.
Furthermore, you need to enclose the whole condition in brackets.

Finally it should look like:

```
if (UserNameTextbox.Text == "UserName" 
            && PasswordTextbox.Text == "password") {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the parentheses

```
if(/* some condition */)
{

}
```

And C# uses double-equals (`==`) for equality, not a single one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if( UserNameTextbox.Text == "UserName" 
            && PasswordTextbox.Text == "password" )
        {
        GameSelect gs = new GameSelect();
        gs.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its helpful when answering questions on SO to describe what changes you've made to code rather than just correct it and leave it to the reader to compare your answer to the original post

Answer (score 0):

For comparison you will have to use == and we use = only for assignment.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (UserNameTextbox.Text == "UserName"  && PasswordTextbox.Text == "password")
  {
    GameSelect gs = new GameSelect();
    gs.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```